# extract whole http request via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My goal is to extract the whole http request from the `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` event. Since this event doesn't give this information, such as headers, type of the request (POST,GET,..). I am using another event `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`.
The second event gives all needed information, but it occurs more often.

how can I "combine" those events?  All I need is all headrs,request type etc of the download file event

I tried to declare a global variable like:

```
var request_detailes;
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function (details) {
        request_detailes= details;
        return {
            requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
        };
    }, {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    },
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]);

chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(foo);

function foo()
{
// here I'm using request_detailes...
}
```

my solution works but not always since the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` occur very often

[chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads)